# No suitable constructor to convert from enum to underlying type

Tags: c++, enums, underlyingtype

I have an enum class as defined here

```
// namespace Types
enum class MessageType : uint32_t
{
  COMPUTE_SUM_MESSAGE = 1
};
```

I want a function that can take an enum value and convert it to a byte array. I tried to use `underlying_type` to convert my enum value from a `MessageType` to an `uint32_t` but I get a no suitable constructor exists to convert it.

```
void ConvertMessageTypeToByteArray(Types::MessageType message_type)
{
  using MessageTypeUnderlying = std::underlying_type<Types::MessageType>;
  // Can not static cast the message_type to MessageTypeUnderlying 
  MessageTypeUnderlying data = static_cast<MessageTypeUnderlying>(message_type);
}
```

Is it possible to do something similar to this? I would like to have `message_type` as an unsigned 32 bit integer, which is its underlying type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `using` statement is wrong. It is defining  `MessageTypeUnderlying` as an alias for the [`std::underlying_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/underlying_type) struct itself, not the enum's actual underlying type that it represents. Thus, you get the error when you try to cast an enum value to the struct type. The compiler's full error message should be pointing this out to you.

To fix this, you need to instead define `MessageTypeUnderlying` as an alias for the type that is specified by the `std::underlying_type::type` field:

> **Member types**
>
> | Name | Definition |
> | --- | --- |
> | `type` | the underlying type of `T` |

```cpp
using MessageTypeUnderlying = std::underlying_type<Types::MessageType>::type;
```

Alternatively, in C++14 and later, you can use the helper `std::underlying_type_t` alias instead:

> **Helper types**
>
> ```cpp
> template< class T >
> using underlying_type_t = typename underlying_type<T>::type;
> ```

```
using MessageTypeUnderlying = std::underlying_type_t<Types::MessageType>;
```

That being said, C++23 adds [`std::to_underlying()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/to_underlying), which does exactly what you are trying to do manually:

> Converts an enumeration to its underlying type. Equivalent to `return static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<Enum>>(e);`.

```
auto data = std::to_underlying(message_type);
```

Comment: Is the `typename` needed on the right hand side because it is a dependent name?

Comment: @nick2225 it is not a dependent name, actually, so the `typename` is not needed. I have removed it. See [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/)